# FtpEasyTransfer - .NET5 Worker Service for Easy FTP Sync'ing

Tags: c#, .net-5

I've created a simple worker service, which uses FluentFTP to sync either files or directories from one ftp client to another, or simply to a local machine, depending on how appsettings.json is configured. Overall I'm pretty happy with the code, but there's certain points I find the code repeats itself or looks a bit messy. This is the first micro-service I've finished, would love some thoughts on how I can improve it.

```
public class FtpWorker : IFtpWorker
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FtpWorker> _logger;
        private TransferSettingsOptions _options;
        private string _localDirectory;

        public FtpWorker(ILogger<FtpWorker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task RunAsync(TransferSettingsOptions options)
        {
            _options = options;
            _localDirectory = _options.LocalPath;

            if (!_options.LocalPathIsFile)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_options.LocalPath);
            }

            switch (DetermineRunMode())
            {
                case RunMode.DownloadDir:
                    await RunDownloadDirAsync();
                    break;
                case RunMode.DownloadFile:
                    await RunDownloadFileAsync();
                    break;
                case RunMode.UploadDir:
                    await RunUploadDirAsync();
                    break;
                case RunMode.UploadFile:
                    await RunUploadFileAsync();
                    break;
                case RunMode.SyncDirs:
                    await RunSyncDirsAsync();
                    break;
                case RunMode.SyncFile:
                    await RunSyncFileAsync();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            };
        }

        private async Task RunDownloadDirAsync()
        {
            if (_options.Source is not null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.Source.Server))
            {
                try
                {
                    await DownloadDirectoryFromSourceAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Exception in RunDownloadDirAsync: {Message}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task RunDownloadFileAsync()
        {
            if (_options.Source is not null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.Source.Server))
            {
                try
                {
                    await DownloadFileFromSourceAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Exception in RunDownloadDirAsync: {Message}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task RunUploadDirAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private async Task RunUploadFileAsync()
        {
            if (_options.Destination != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.Destination.Server))
            {
                try
                {
                    await UploadFileToDestinationAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Exception in RunUploadFileAsync: {Message}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError("Destination or DestinationServer empty in RunUploadFile");
            }
        }

        private async Task RunSyncDirsAsync()
        {
            if (_options.Source != null || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.Source.Server))
            {
                try
                {
                    await DownloadDirectoryFromSourceAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Exception in DownloadFromSource: {Message}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("No source configured.");
            }

            foreach (var opt in _options.ChangeExtensions)
            {
                ChangeFileExtensions(opt);
            }

            if (_options.Destination != null || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.Destination.Server))
            {
                try
                {
                    await UploadDirectoryToDestinationAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Exception in UploadToDestination: {Message}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("No destination configured.");
            }
        }

        private Task RunSyncFileAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private async Task<List<FtpResult>> DownloadDirectoryFromSourceAsync()
        {
            var token = new CancellationToken();


            using (var ftp = new FtpClient(_options.Source.Server, _options.Source.Port, _options.Source.User, _options.Source.Password))
            {
                ftp.OnLogEvent += Log;

                await ftp.ConnectAsync(token);

                var rules = new List<FtpRule>
                {
                    new FtpFileExtensionRule(true, _options.Source.FileTypesToDownload)
                };

                var results = await ftp.DownloadDirectoryAsync(_options.LocalPath, _options.Source.RemotePath, FtpFolderSyncMode.Update,
                    FtpLocalExists.Skip, FtpVerify.None, rules);

                if (_options.Source.DeleteOnceDownloaded)
                {
                    foreach (var download in results)
                    {
                        if (download.IsSuccess && download.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)
                        {
                            await ftp.DeleteFileAsync(download.RemotePath);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var download in results)
                {
                    if (download.IsFailed)
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("Download of {Name} failed: {Exception}", download.Name, download.Exception);
                    }
                }

                return results;
            }
        }

        private async Task<FtpStatus> DownloadFileFromSourceAsync()
        {
            var token = new CancellationToken();

            using (var ftp = new FtpClient(_options.Source.Server, _options.Source.Port, _options.Source.User, _options.Source.Password))
            {
                ftp.OnLogEvent += Log;

                await ftp.ConnectAsync(token);

                var overwriteExisting = _options.Source.OverwriteExisting ? FtpLocalExists.Overwrite : FtpLocalExists.Skip;

                string localPath = _options.Destination.RemotePath;

                if (!_options.LocalPathIsFile)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(_options.Source.RemotePath);
                    localPath = $"{_options.LocalPath}/{fileName}";
                }

                var result = await ftp.DownloadFileAsync(localPath, _options.Source.RemotePath, overwriteExisting);

                if (_options.Source.DeleteOnceDownloaded)
                {
                    if (result.IsSuccess())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await ftp.DeleteFileAsync(_options.Source.RemotePath, token);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning("Error deleting {RemotePath}: {Message}", _options.Source.RemotePath, ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        private void ChangeFileExtensions(ChangeExtensionsOptions options)
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(_localDirectory, $"*.{options.Source}"))
            {
                var newFileName = @$"{_localDirectory}\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}.{options.Target}";
                try
                {
                    File.Move(file, newFileName, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Moving file {file} failed: {Message}", file, ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }

        private async Task<FtpStatus> UploadFileToDestinationAsync()
        {
            var token = new CancellationToken();

            using (var ftp = new FtpClient(_options.Destination.Server, _options.Destination.Port, _options.Destination.User, _options.Destination.Password))
            {
                ftp.OnLogEvent += Log;

                await ftp.ConnectAsync(token);

                var overwriteExisting = _options.Destination.OverwriteExisting ? FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite : FtpRemoteExists.Skip;

                string remotePath = _options.Destination.RemotePath;

                if (!_options.Destination.RemotePathIsFile)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(_options.LocalPath);
                    remotePath = $"{_options.Destination.RemotePath}/{fileName}";
                }

                var result = await ftp.UploadFileAsync(_options.LocalPath, remotePath, overwriteExisting);

                if (_options.Destination.DeleteOnceUploaded)
                {
                    if (result.IsSuccess())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (_options.LocalPathIsFile)
                            {
                                File.Delete(_options.LocalPath);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning("Error deleting {LocalPath}: {Message}", _options.LocalPath, ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return result;
            };
        }

        private async Task<List<FtpResult>> UploadDirectoryToDestinationAsync()
        {
            var token = new CancellationToken();

            using (var ftp = new FtpClient(_options.Destination.Server, _options.Destination.Port, _options.Destination.User, _options.Destination.Password))
            {
                ftp.OnLogEvent += Log;

                await ftp.ConnectAsync(token);

                var results = await ftp.UploadDirectoryAsync(_options.LocalPath, _options.Destination.RemotePath, FtpFolderSyncMode.Update,
                    FtpRemoteExists.Skip, FtpVerify.None);

                if (_options.Destination.DeleteOnceUploaded)
                {
                    foreach (var upload in results)
                    {
                        if (upload.IsSuccess)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                File.Delete(upload.LocalPath);
                                _logger.LogInformation("File deleted: {LocalPath}", upload.LocalPath);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                _logger.LogWarning("Error deleting file {LocalPath}: {Message}", upload.LocalPath, ex.Message);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var upload in results)
                {
                    if (upload.IsFailed)
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("Upload of {LocalPath} failed: {Exception}", upload.LocalPath, upload.Exception);
                    }
                }

                return results;
            }
        }

        private RunMode DetermineRunMode()
        {
            if (_options.LocalPathIsFile)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Local Path: {LocalPath} is file, RunMode determined as UploadFile", _options.LocalPath);
                return RunMode.UploadFile;
            }
            else if (_options.Source is not null && _options.Destination is not null)
            {
                if (_options.Source.RemotePathIsFile)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Source & Destination defined, Source.RemotePath: {RemotePath} is file, RunMode determined as SyncFile", _options.Source.RemotePath);
                    return RunMode.SyncFile;
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Source & Destination defined, Source.RemotePath: {RemotePath} is directory, RunMode determined as SyncDirs", _options.Source.RemotePath);
                    return RunMode.SyncDirs;
                }
            }
            else if (_options.Source is null && _options.Destination is not null)
            {
                if (_options.Destination.RemotePathIsFile)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Only Destination defined, Destination.RemotePath: {RemotePath} is file, RunMode determined as UploadFile", _options.Destination.RemotePath);
                    return RunMode.UploadFile;
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Only Destination defined, Destination.RemotePath: {RemotePath} is directory, RunMode determined as UploadDir", _options.Destination.RemotePath);
                    return RunMode.UploadDir;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_options.Source.RemotePathIsFile)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Only Source defined, Source.RemotePath: {RemotePath} is file, RunMode determined as DownloadFile", _options.Source.RemotePath);
                    return RunMode.DownloadFile;
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Only Source defined, Source.RemotePath: {RemotePath} is directory, RunMode determined as DownloadDir", _options.Source.RemotePath);
                    return RunMode.DownloadDir;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm curious if there's an easier way to handle the using statements, as I seem to be passing in params in the same way every time, is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick remarks:

- I notice you always use `ex.Message`. However, what if you've got an `InnerException`? I'd recommend an approach [like this](https://github.com/BJMdotNET/code-samples/blob/master/ExceptionMessageRetriever.cs) (I've copied the code of the method below; note that you can adapt the `string.Join` to your own liking, of course). Also, I'd also recommend to log the entire stack trace as well, in case you run into an exception where the message doesn't tell you enough.

  ```
   public static string Execute(Exception exc)
   {
       var messages = new List<string>();
       do
       {
           messages.Add(exc.Message);
           exc = exc.InnerException;
       }
       while (exc != null);

       return string.Join(" - ", messages);
   }
  ```
- In several places you use `new FtpClient(_options.Source.Server, _options.Source.Port, _options.Source.User, _options.Source.Password)`. Move this to a method and call that method. Same with `new FtpClient(_options.Destination.Server, _options.Destination.Port, _options.Destination.User, _options.Destination.Password)`.

  Matter of fact, if `_options.Source` and `_options.Destination` are the same type (which I'd expect, but you haven't posted this class), I'd recommend a method that accepts this class as a parameter and returns an `FtpClient`.
- `DetermineRunMode()` is too noisy and repetitive and inelegant for me. I'd favor an approach where you'd determine various factors (e.g. whether both `Source` and `Destination` are defined) and at the end compile a message, e.g.

  ```
  var sourceIsNotNull = _options.Source is not null;
  var destinationIsNotNull = _options.Destination is not null;
  var message = (sourceIsNotNull && destinationIsNotNull)
                   ? "Source & Destination defined"
                   : sourceIsNotNull
                        ? "Only Source defined"
                        : "Only Destination defined";
  ```

  Maybe you could have a method for each "factor" e.g. which is defined, what the `RunMode` is, whether `RemotePath` is a file or a folder,..., perhaps even move all that to a separate class (called `RunModeRetriever` or alike).

  (Also, considering you're doing a `return`, I don't think all those `else`s are even necessary.)
- You check too much in the methods themselves. In `RunDownloadDirAsync` you already know that `_options.Source is not null` (because that is checked in `DetermineRunMode` and `RunDownloadDirAsync` is called due to the result of that method call) so there is no need to be "extra careful": this only adds noise to your logic. You aren't even consistent: you log `_logger.LogError("Destination or DestinationServer empty in RunUploadFile");`, but there is no equivalent for `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.Source.Server)`.

  You should move all those checks before executing `DetermineRunMode`, perhaps even rethink that logic into a "data check" class which looks at the `TransferSettingsOptions`, verifies all the necessary data is in there, returns a "fail" if there is required data missing combined with a report of what is missing, and returns a "success" when all is OK, and perhaps also determines the `RunMode` while doing all those checks.

  Or perhaps you should group the data checks, return a report, and based on that report either you stop execution of the method and report to the user why you have stopped execution, or you continue the execution by determining the `RunMode` (using the data in the data check report), and then call the relevant method without having to worry that a certain setting is missing.

  **The important point is to group your functionality, that way you can remove redundant code and improve the logic flow of the method.**
- Each method has a `try...catch`. Why not put the `try...catch` around the `switch (DetermineRunMode())` instead? Just make sure to include the `RunMode` when you log any eventual `Exception`.

Comment: Thank you, the extension method for exceptions is very useful, I hadn't even considered that, and I knew there was an easier way to set up the using statements, thanks again.

Regarding your comments on `DetermineRunMode()`, I'm not sure I understand how your proposed changes would improve things, isn't adding a load of inline conditionals just confusing things further?

Comment: Ah, actually I see, redundant calls, you're just putting the booleans in variables so they don't have to go `if source is null` then next time `if source is not null`, got it!

Comment: @GaryMacGregor-Manzi It's not only the redundancy of the calls, but also the constant switching of functionality: you check the data, then you determine the RunMode, then you call a specific method based on the RunMode, which then does more data checking. Group the functionality: first check the data, because there is no point in doing the rest of the actions if that is incomplete. Then determine the RunMode, then execute the relevant method.

Comment: I've removed some extraneous checks, but the reason `DetermineRunMode()` checks if source/destination are null, is my aim is to use appsettings.json to automatically determine which mode to use - so for example if the user leaves the destination out completely, the code will determine it only wants to download, so it's perfectly valid to not have a destination or source depending on the situation. Unsure how to break it down further without performing the same checks repeatedly

Comment: @GaryMacGregor-Manzi If the destination is optional, then it shouldn't be part of the data checks (or it can be but it shouldn't be a cause to stop the execution). My point is that you do `_options.Source is not null` inside the method that is only called if `_options.Source` isn't null, so that check is redundant. Then you check `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.Source.Server)` which isn't in the right place, because if that is a required value it should be checked before the method is called, i.e. before `DetermineRunMode` is called. Group your functionality instead of mixing it all over.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thank you for your patience!